# When was the Sifre redacted?

Tags: history, jewish-books, midrash

When was the redaction of the Sifre (midrash halakha on Bamidbar and Devarim)?  I would like to know in context with Mishna, Tosefta, and other Tannaitic literature.  Please source your answers.

Comment: By "in context" you mean whether it was published before them or after them?

Comment: Yes.  Kind of like a timeline?

Comment: According to R' Yochanan in Sanhedrin (86a), the unsourced teachings of the Sifri were written by R' Shimon. Even if it was compiled after his time from his teachings, it was at least written by the time of R' Yochanan, who said that teaching in Sanhedrin. Thus, it would have been written no earlier than the early second century nor later than the mid-third century.

Answer (score 3):

Sifre appears to be redacted by mid-third century CE. See [Fraide's From Tradition to Commentary: Torah and its Interpretation in the Midrash Sifre to Deuteronomy](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=2c7eSmDSWqwC&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=sifre%20redaction&ots=HUMazCam2x&sig=jS6pf1mm6SFtbl9Dq7T6gfMYuuA#v=onepage&q=redacted&f=false)

This would place it slightly after Mishna with its redaction at 220 CE, something widely accepted and available on Wikipedia as well. Academic debates aside, this would also place it slightly after/around Tosefta, which was collected contemporaneously to the Mishna.

Comment: 220 CE _is_ the middle of the third century!

Comment: @DoubleAA late night, corrected.